# How to copy my friends' skype username?

Tags: skype

I can check their profile but the text there is not copyable. Worst, the name that show up on the chat is different than the name in the profile so I wonder which one is right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you check their profile, you can right click on their username and select copy. :)

[image: pic 1]

[image: pic 2]